# What can I do with Actionscript Communication files?

Tags: adobe-media-server

Is there any documentation about `.asc` files to be used with Adobe Media Server?

I want to create an Adobe Media Server application where you can record videos and save them to a server.

The client flash application won't be able to save the files server-side, I assume, so I'm thinking that you might be able to save the files server-side using the `.asc` file.

But I haven't been able to find any documentation about `.asc` files or what they can do. It doesn't look like I can just import AS3 classes like `File` and save things that way.
Is there any documentation or API that explains what I can do with a `.asc` file?

---

I found this [Server-Side Actionscript Language Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11aff5ba-7f8bSSASLR.2.3.html), which says that this is actually just Javascript 1.5

So that's a lot of good information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11aff5ba-7f8bSSASLR.2.3.html

You are right, you can not use AS3 on server side applications.

You can use server-side Actionscript, wich is the equivalent to Javascript 1.5. FMS has a javascript engine that executes server-side scripts.

Also, you will notice that you can name the files either .asc or .js.